# use mat buttons to build a nav bar in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, button, angular-material

I am building an application in angular. As part of it, I am developing a navbar using mat buttons.

```
<div flexLayout="row">
  <button class="flat_button" mat-flat-button>B2-L1</button>
  <button mat-flat-button>B2-L3</button>
  <button mat-flat-button>B2-L3</button>
  <button mat-flat-button>B2-L4</button>
</div>
```

```
.mat-flat-button {
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 0 px !important;
}

.mat-button {
  border-radius: 0 px !important;
}
```

I have changed the background color of the button, now if I select a button I want its color to be white,(whatever button I select/click it should be white and rest should be grey in color). I have tried several things but not able to do. can some one help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a minimal working demo in stackblitz?

Comment: when you say `select a button`, do you mean `click/hover a button` ??

Comment: select a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to set a variable, say `selectedTab` on `click` of the `mat-flat-button` and use `ngClass` to add the `active` class based on the `selectedTab`.

```html
<div flexLayout="row">
    <button (click)="selectedTab = 1" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedTab === 1}" mat-flat-button>B2-L1</button>
    <button (click)="selectedTab = 2" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedTab === 2}" mat-flat-button>B2-L3</button>
    <button (click)="selectedTab = 3" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedTab === 3}" mat-flat-button>B2-L3</button>
    <button (click)="selectedTab = 4" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedTab === 4}" mat-flat-button>B2-L4</button>
</div>
```

where the `active` class would look something like this.

```css
.mat-flat-button.active {
    background-color: white;
}
```

**Note**: I'm not sure if it was a typo in your code but there should be no space between `0` and `px`. It will not apply if used like that. The `!important` is also not needed. Instead, you can try this.

```css
.mat-flat-button {
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several events on buttons where you can change the color.

- `:focus` will change color after click.
- `:active` will change color while clicking.
- `:hover` will change color while hovering on button.

I think here you are looking for `:focus`.

```
.mat-flat-button:focus {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nebhrz) you can find a demo.

Comment: This will only partly work, If the user clicks outside, he would still want the tab to be shown as active. But since you are using the `focus` event, the button will lose it's active state again.